# Nested boolean query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an sql query like

```
select student_name,roll_number 
from
mytable
where
(course = 'CCNA' or course = 'MCSE') and course NOT Like '%network%'
```

How can i create an equivalent `nested boolean query` in `elasticsearch`?

Comment: Refer bool-query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query

Comment: How do I include or criteria here?

Comment: have you tried `terms` query?

Comment: You may also try the `should` part of the `bool` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query might help you, This query responds with records which course does not contain a "network" keyword and course has a value "ccna" or "mcse".
I have not considered a case sensitiveness feature here and assumed that you have a default mapping.

```
POST study-doc*/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "bool": {
                   "should": [
                      {
                          "term": {
                             "course": {
                                "value": "ccna"
                             }
                          }
                      },{
                          "term": {
                             "course": {
                                "value": "msce"
                             }
                          }
                      }
                   ]
               }},
               {
               "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                           "wildcard": {
                              "course.keyword": {
                                 "value": "^((?!network).)*$"
                              }
                           }
                       }
                    ]    
               }
           }

        ]
    }
}
}
```